# Can Mathml put a <mmultiscripts> inside a <mfrac>?

Tags: html, mathml

I'm trying to use MathML to display a fraction with combinations on top and bottom, using the nCk notation for combinations. If I do it the easiest way, e.g. '12c5', I have no problem. But if I try to use an italicized capital 'C' flanked by subscripts, I run into a problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/cx2aks49/2/

Here is a snippet of code:

```
<math mathsize='1.5em'>
    <mrow>
        <mfrac>
            <mrow>
                <mi>(
                    <mmultiscripts>
                        <mi mathvariant='italic'>C</mi>
                        <mn>3</mn>
                        <none/>
                        <mprescripts/>
                        <mn>5</mn>
                        <none/>
                    </mmultiscripts>) (
                    <mmultiscripts>
                        <mi mathvariant='italic'>C</mi>
                        <mn>2</mn>
                        <none/>
                        <mprescripts/>
                        <mn>7</mn>
                        <none/>
                    </mmultiscripts>)</mi>
            </mrow>
            <mi>
                <mmultiscripts>
                    <mi mathvariant='italic'>C</mi>
                    <mn>5</mn>
                    <none/>
                    <mprescripts/>
                    <mn>12</mn>
                    <none/>
                </mmultiscripts>
            </mi>
        </mfrac>
        <mo>=</mo>
        <mfrac>
            <mn>35</mn>
            <mn>132</mn>
        </mfrac>
    </mrow>
</math>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MathML code is invalid. You should have something like

```
<math mathsize='1.5em'>
    <mrow>
        <mfrac>
            <mrow>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mmultiscripts>
                    <mo mathvariant='italic'>C</mo>
                    <mn>3</mn>
                    <none/>
                    <mprescripts/>
                    <mn>5</mn>
                    <none/>
                </mmultiscripts>
                <mo>)</mo>
                <mo>(</mo>
                <mmultiscripts>
                    <mo mathvariant='italic'>C</mo>
                    <mn>2</mn>
                    <none/>
                    <mprescripts/>
                    <mn>7</mn>
                    <none/>
                </mmultiscripts>
                <mo>)</mo>
            </mrow>
            <mmultiscripts>
                <mo mathvariant='italic'>C</mo>
                <mn>5</mn>
                <none/>
                <mprescripts/>
                <mn>12</mn>
                <none/>
            </mmultiscripts>
        </mfrac>
        <mo>=</mo>
        <mfrac>
            <mn>35</mn>
            <mn>132</mn>
        </mfrac>
    </mrow>
</math>
```

Short explanation: fences are operators (see the examples at http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter3.html#presm.mo) and you should avoid the `mo` around the `mmultiscropts` (see the examples at http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter3.html#presm.mmultiscripts).

Comment: Thanks, it's working now, so it looks like you're right. One quick point: when you say avoid the `mo`, do you mean avoid the `mi`? Thanks again.

Comment: You should avoid `mi`, `mo` and `mn` around `mmultiscropts`. I said `mo` because since fence are operators you could thought that only replace the `mi` with `mo` will work.